# In Plotly, can I have customized hover text in a heatmap?

Tags: python, plotly

I noticed that in some graph types, there is a "t" argument that will allow customized hover text. This argument seems to be missing from the heat map API. Is there another way to implement it? I would like to have actual informative labels instead of "x:", "y:" and "z:".

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The `t` key is not currently supported in plotly heatmaps, unfortunately.</strike>

The `t` key is now available for `heatmap` and `contour` trace types.

Here's an example of a heatmap with hover text: https://plot.ly/~etpinard/2096/heatmap-with-hover-text/